# When is a configuration a Halbach configuration?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, halbach-array

I just started reading about [Halbach arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halbach_array). What I don't understand, is how do you know you have a magnet configuration which is Halbach? Is there a unique formula for the magnetic directions which should be valid?

Comment: Essentially, the OP asks, does some quantitatical measurement exist for the "halbach-ness" of a magnet array. I think, the ratio of field-square on the two sides would be a characteristic data for that, but it is only my layman's intuition. The question is, in my opinion, surely clear.